How can I build a floor over a garage slab that floods?
I have a garage that was converted to an apartment. When there is a heavy rain it floods.
I would like to raise the floor with joists that are waterproof if that exists. I am willing to use concrete joists that can be waterproofed as well. Does anyone have any recommendations?
We have added a multitude of drainage fixes but if the water has no way to go out. Because of the lack of drainage it's my only option.

Have you added a sump pit and pump to pump the water up and away?  Can ask on the law site if the city has to maintain the drains(location required) and if cities insurance or lawsuit can help.

I've removed your political rant and family story. They aren't relevant to your question. Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then revise further as needed. Be sure you stick to just the facts, please.

How deep of water do you need to accommodate? This strikes me as an XY question. If you can reliably predict water depth you can presumably lower that expected depth.

Really, the answer is to fix the drainage problem that leads to the garage/apartment flooding.

Unless you fix the flooding, the area under your new floor will just get musty and moldy.

If you do need to build what's essentially a dock, build a dock. Or at least a deck.

Use pre-cast concrete pavers or piers, or metal standoffs, depending on the height needed.
 

Build the floor structure to modern standards for live loads with pressure-treated lumber.

Overlay a waterproofing membrane before installing the floor sheathing, sealed to the outer wall.

Allow ventilation to prevent putrification of the area underneath.


